# BlackJack Project - Can't make aces change from 11 to 1's

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, project, blackjack

I'm currently making a blackjack game for my project in school in Visual Basic.

In blackjack, when you have aces (value initially 11) their value turns to 1 when the total value of the cards is > 21. In code, this would just take away 10 for every ace

I'm stuck on this.

This is the code I have (that doesn't work):

```
Do While PlayerValue > 21 And counter <= noAcesPlayer
        counter += 1
        PlayerValue -= 10
Loop
```

In a senario, I have a: 2, 8, A, 8 (=29)
But since there is an Ace, and the total value is > 21, the value should have 10 subtracted from it (=19) - the above code does not do this.

Another scenario would be 10, 8, A, A (=40)
Again, the two Aces should turn into 1's, since the total value > 21, giving 20.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What value do you get in both example cases, instead of the right value? Do `PlayerValue` and `counter`have the right initial values when you use the debugger?

Comment: my guess is that `counter` or `noAcesPlayer` (both of which we have to guess what they are) doesnt have the value you think it does, so the loop is never entered.  Use a break point to examine their value.

Comment: Agree with @Plutonix. Did you reset `counter` before/after the loop?  `counter = 0`

Comment: Yeah guys, counter is set to zero.

Comment: A better algorithm is this: (a) treat aces as 1; (b) whenever a hand contains an ace, set a flag--no need to keep track of how many; (c) if the final total is < 12, and the flag is set, add 10.  That's it.  No loop, just a simple flag, and quick tests.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach

```
Public Enum CardFace
    None
    Ace
    Two
    Three
    Four
    Five
    Six
    Seven
    Eight
    Nine
    Ten
    Jack
    Queen
    King
End Enum
```

This code should produce a value of twenty

```
    Dim cards As New List(Of CardFace) From {CardFace.Ten, CardFace.Eight, CardFace.Ace, CardFace.Ace}
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    Dim numofAces As Integer = 0
    For Each c As CardFace In cards
        Debug.WriteLine(c.ToString)
        If c = CardFace.Ace Then
            numofAces += 1
        Else
            total += c
        End If
    Next

    If numofAces > 0 Then
        If total + 11 + (numofAces - 1) > 21 Then
            total += numofAces
        Else
            total += 11 + (numofAces - 1)
        End If
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine(total)
```

Comment: Hi man, Thank you alot! The code you gave me pretty much worked (made a few modifications - nothing major). Brilliant. Owe you big time!

Comment: Not brilliant, just mimics what people do if you think about it.

Comment: True. I should've had my breakfast this morning! :D

Comment: Keeping number of aces and using a loop is unnecessary. You only ever add 10 once, or not at all. So just use a flag and an if-then.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - Keeping the count seemed to be a good idea, but the loop was not required.  Modified the example.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to build a blackjack hand is the following (in pseudo-code):

```
Variables: total = 0, soft-flag = false

For each card in hand:
    Add card value to total. Faces are 10, aces are 1.
    If the card you added was an ace, set soft-flag = true

If total < 12 and soft-flag:
    Add 10 to total
Else:
    set soft-flag = false
```

That's it. Only one loop over the cards, no extraneous variables, and you're left with the total value and a flag indicating if the total is soft.